# Get all variables in bash from text line

Tags: regex, bash, variables, sed

Suppose I have a text line like

```
echo -e "$text is now set for ${items[$i]} and count is ${#items[@]} and this number is $((i+1))"
```

I need to get all variables (for example, using sed) so that after all I have list containing: $text, ${items[$i]}, $i, ${#items[@]}, $((i+1)).

I am writing script which have some complex commands and before executing each command it prompts it to user. So when my script prompts command like "pacman -S ${softtitles[$i]}" you can't guess what this command is actually does. I just want to add a list of variables used in this command below and it's values. So I decided to do it via regex and sed, but I can't do it properly :/

UPD: It can be just a string like echo "$test is 'ololo', ${items[$i]} is 'today', $i is 3", it doesn't need to be list at all and it can include any temporary variables and multiple lines of code. Also it doesn't have to be sed :)

## SOLUTION:

```
echo $m | grep -oP '(?<!\[)\$[{(]?[^"\s\/\047.\\]+[})]?' | uniq > vars
```

`$m` - our line of code with several bash variables, like `"This is $string with ${some[$i]} variables"`

`uniq` - if we have string with multiple same variables, this will remove dublicates

`vars` - temporary file to hold all variables found in text string

### Next piece of code will show all variables and its values in fancy style:

```
if [ ! "`cat vars`" == "" ]; then
    while read -r p; do
        value=`eval echo $p`
        Style=`echo -e "$Style\n\t$Green$p = $value$Def"`
    done < vars
fi
```

`$Style` - predefined variable with some text (title of the command)

`$Green`, `$Def` - just `tput` settings of color (green -> text -> default)

```
Green=`tput setaf 2`
Def=`tput sgr0`
```

`$p` - each line of `vars` file (all variables one by one) looped by `while read -r p` loop.

Comment: how you produce the output as list through sed?

Comment: It can be just a string like `echo "$test is 'ololo', ${items[$i]} is 'today', $i is 3"`, it doesn't need to be list at all and it can include any temporary variables and multiple lines of code. Also it doesn't have to be sed :)

Comment: Your variables can't nest to arbitrary depth if you want to use regex. You should add `${foo+${bar-"No ${foo}bar"}}` to your test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the below grep command,

```
$ grep -oP '(?<!\[)(\$[^"\s]+)' file
$text
${items[$i]}
${#items[@]}
$((i+1))
```

Comment: For this particular case, `grep -oP '\$[^"\s]+' file` outputs the same. What is the purpose of `(?<!\[)`?

Comment: Well, thx to you too, this works as well as Kalanidhi answer, but also has several wrong matches, but I think it's easy to improve.

Comment: @EwanCoder post some examples of wrong matches . I'll try to answer it.

Comment: @fedorqui it won't match the `$` which was present just after to `[`

Comment: @AvinashRaj for example, `)`, `'` and `;` symbols at the end of a variable, also ${gitfolder[$i]}/$j were parsed as one variable but should be as two (full command is `cd ${gitfolder[$i]}/$j`) and etc. minor mismatches, I think I can handle it.

UPD: There's an example of a file https://github.com/ewancoder/eal/blob/master/peal.sh

Comment: @EwanCoder try `grep -oP '(?<!\[)\$[{(]?[^"\s\/]+[})]?' file`

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's better but still `)`, `;`, `'`, `\` remain at the end of variables.

Comment: `That's better but still ), ;, ', ```, unclear for me. Provide some examples.

Comment: @AvinashRaj example: `sed -i -e "s/^Address=.*/Address='$ip\/24'/" /etc/netctl/$profile`

In this line variable `$ip` is grepped as `$ip\\`

Comment: try this regex `(?<!\[)\$[{(]?[^"\s\/\\]+[})]?`

Comment: Now it works perfectly, testing just now on all my files (working in code).

One more thing: it doesn't seem to catch `$i` inside `${some_variable[$i]}` structure, have any idea how to do it? Also I'm grepping lines one by one, so when there's multiple structures like `${some_variable[$i]}` it should grep `$i` only once.

Comment: @EwanCoder could you provide all the possible input with the expected output? I think you could figure out your needs easily.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I've already changed it so it works perfectly for me, thx for reply :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure its perfect , but it will help for you

```
sed -r  's/(\$[^ "]+)/\n\1\n/g' filename | sed -n '/^\$/p'
```

Explanation :

```
(\$[^ "]+)    - Match the character $ followed by any charter until whitespace or double quote.
\n\1\n        - Matched word before and after put newlines ( so the variable present in separate line ) .
/^\$/p        - start with $ print the line like print variable
```

Comment: Wow, thx, works almost as I needed. Although there are some wrong matches, this is good starting point. I guess I can improve your answer a little bit and get proper behavior.

Answer (score 1):

A few approaches, I tested each of them on `file` which contains

```
echo -e "$text is now set for ${items[$i]} and count is ${#items[@]} and this number is $((i+1))"
```

1. grep

   ```
   $ grep -oP '\$[^ "]*' file 
   $text
   ${items[$i]}
   ${#items[@]}
   $((i+1))
   ```
2. perl

   ```
   $ perl -ne '@f=(/\$[^ "]*/g); print "@f"' file 
   $text ${items[$i]} ${#items[@]} $((i+1))
   ```

   or

   ```
   $ perl -ne '@f=(/\$[^ "]*/g); print join "\n",@f' file 
   $text
   ${items[$i]}
   ${#items[@]}
   $((i+1))
   ```

The idea is the same in all of them. They will collect the list of strings that start with a `$` and as many subsequent characters as possible that are neither spaces nor `"`.